# Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'names.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron

Im getting the error `Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'names.json'` and I have tried adding this code to my main.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const directory = path.join('data', 'names.json')
```

In builded version I get the err but when running the app with node it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the names.json file in the same folder as the .exe you are running.

The error explains the problem. "no such file or directory"

I can see in this line:

```
var names = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('names.json')).nameList;
```

The code is looking for the names.json file in the root of the application. You should be able to specify a folder structure as well.
:)

eg:`var names = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./exampleFolder/names.json')).nameList;`